# Java Generics - complexer example with inheritance and interface

Tags: java, generics

Most Java tutorials on "Generics" explain either working with Classes and Methods. That's quite simple.

Putting all together in a more complex example is not trivial. I get a number of compile errors.

Can you help getting this complex example right? It may be useful for others as well. I know also that the BaseObjectData is of course not right.

The interface:

```
public interface ComparatorBase<T> {
    List<Difference> isSame(T otherObject);
}
```

With Difference:

```
public record Difference(String id, String left, String right) { }
```

The base class is (**Errors**: unknow methods: otherObject.getId() or getObjectValue1()):

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
public class BaseObjectData<T> implements ComparatorBase<T> {
    private String id;
    private String objectValue1;
    private String objectValue2;

    @Override
    public List<Difference> isSame(T otherObject) {
        List<Difference> differences = new ArrayList<>();
        if( ! getObjectValue1().equals( otherObject.getObjectValue1())) {
            differences.add( new Difference( getId(), getObjectValue1(), otherObject.getObjectValue1()));
        }
        if( ! getObjectValue2().equals( otherObject.getObjectValue2())) {
            differences.add( new Difference( getId(), getObjectValue2(), otherObject.getObjectValue2()));
        }
        return differences;
    }

    T findMatchingObject( List<T> otherObjects) {
        for( T object: otherObjects) {
            if( object.getId().equals( id)) {
                return object;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then an inherited class: (**Error**: unknown method: otherObject.getObjectValue3())

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class InheritLevel1Data<T> extends BaseObjectData implements ComparatorBase<T> {
    private String objectValue3;

    public InheritLevel1Data( String id, String d1, String d2, String d3) {
        super( id, d1, d2);
        this.objectValue3 = d3;
    }
    @Override
    public List<Difference> isSame(T otherObject) {
        List<Difference> differences = super.isSame( otherObject);
        if( ! getObjectValue3().equals( otherObject.getObjectValue3())) {
            differences.add( new Difference( getId(), getObjectValue3(), otherObject.getObjectValue3()));
        }
        return differences;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class RunnerTest {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( "My logger");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BaseObjectData> objectDataList1 = buildList( "id-1", "data-1", "data-2", "data-3b");
        List<BaseObjectData> objectDataList2 = buildList( "id-1", "data-1", "data-2a", "data-3");
        List<Difference> differences = new ArrayList<>();
        for( BaseObjectData o: objectDataList1) {
            BaseObjectData o2 = (BaseObjectData) o.findMatchingObject( objectDataList2);
            differences.addAll( o.isSame( o2));
        }
        differences.forEach( v -> logger.info( "Verschil: " + v));
    }

    private static List<BaseObjectData> buildList( String id, String data1, String data2, String data3) {
        return List.of(
                new BaseObjectData( "BO_" + id, data1, data2),
                new InheritLevel1Data( "ID1_" + id, data1, data2, data3));
    }
}
```

The output should give the differences: data-2 vs data-2a AND data-3a vs data-3, etc.

Comment: `T` could be literally anything, for example a String or an ArrayList. You have zero guarantee that, whatever your `T` is, it will have a `getObjectValue1()` method, for example. Because, with the code you posted, you are not ensuring that T is of a type that will have those methods.

Comment: Yeah, it should at least extend from the BaseObjectData.

Comment: What do you expect `a.isSame(b)` to do, when `a` is a `InheritLevel1Data` and `b` is a `BaseObjectData`? `otherObject.getObjectValue3()` doesn't make sense in this situation.

Comment: The approach in your edit is what I would do. It doesn't give the desired output because `findMatchingObject` always finds the first object in the list with a matching id, so always the `BaseObjectData` instance. It is unclear why you would expect otherwise.

Comment: Chips, you're right, corrected in the building-list. Now it works. But it was meant for learning more about generics ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@rzwitserloot** - and others - thank you for helping! Much appreciated

**Primary goal** was to perform a deep dive into **Generics** via a complex inheritance example.

My mistake was that I thought that an inherited method signature with a base-class object parameter would (also) match with an inherited object. That is of course not so! That is a different method.

So, inheritedLevel1Data.isSame( InheritedLevel1Data otherObject) is a completely different method signature than the inherited isSame( BaseObjectData otherObject).

Since working with Java 0.92 I was taken by surprise by Java. Never too old to learn ;-)

ComparatorBase:

```
public interface ComparatorBase<T> {
    List<Difference> isSame(T left, T right);
}
```

Data level-0:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class BaseObjectData {
    private String id;
    private String objectValue1;
    private String objectValue2;

    private BaseComparator comparatorBase = new BaseComparator();

    public BaseObjectData(String id, String objectValue1, String objectValue2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.objectValue1 = objectValue1;
        this.objectValue2 = objectValue2;
    }

    public List<Difference> isSame(BaseObjectData otherObject) {
        if(otherObject != null) {
            return comparatorBase.isSame(this, otherObject);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    BaseObjectData findMatchingObject( List<BaseObjectData> otherObjects) {
        for( BaseObjectData object: otherObjects) {
           if( object.getId().equals( id)) {
               return object;
           }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Data level-1:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class InheritLevel1Data extends BaseObjectData {
    private String objectValue3;
    private InheritLevel1Comparator comparatorBase = new InheritLevel1Comparator();

    public InheritLevel1Data(String id, String d1, String d2, String d3) {
        super( id, d1, d2);
        this.objectValue3 = d3;
    }
    // Don't use InheritLevel1Data in the signature
    public List<Difference> isSame(BaseObjectData otherObject) {
        if( otherObject instanceof InheritLevel1Data i1) {
            return comparatorBase.isSame(this, i1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Data level-2: InheritLevel2Data:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class InheritLevel2Data extends InheritLevel1Data  {
    private String objectValue4;
    private InheritLevel2Comparator comparatorBase = new InheritLevel2Comparator();

    public InheritLevel2Data(String id, String d1, String d2, String d3, String d4) {
        super( id, d1, d2,d3);
        this.objectValue4 = d4;
    }

    // Don't use InheritLevel2Data in the signature. 
    public List<Difference> isSame(BaseObjectData otherObject) {
        if( otherObject instanceof InheritLevel2Data i2) {
            return comparatorBase.isSame(this, i2);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Compare level-0:

```
public class BaseComparator<T extends BaseObjectData> implements ComparatorBase<T> {

    public List<Difference> isSame(T left, T right) {
        List<Difference> differences = new ArrayList<>();
        if( ! left.getObjectValue1().equals( right.getObjectValue1())) {
            differences.add( new Difference( left.getId(), left.getObjectValue1(), right.getObjectValue1()));
        }
        if( ! left.getObjectValue2().equals( right.getObjectValue2())) {
            differences.add( new Difference( left.getId(), left.getObjectValue2(), right.getObjectValue2()));
        }
        return differences;
    }
}
```

Compare level 1:

```
public class InheritLevel1Comparator<T extends InheritLevel1Data> extends BaseComparator<T> {
    public List<Difference> isSame(T left, T right) {
        List<Difference> differences = super.isSame(left, right);
        if (!left.getObjectValue3().equals(right.getObjectValue3())) {
            differences.add(new Difference(left.getId(), left.getObjectValue3(), right.getObjectValue3()));
        }
        return differences;
    }
}
```

Compare level-2:

```
public class InheritLevel2Comparator<U extends InheritLevel2Data> extends InheritLevel1Comparator<U> {
    public List<Difference> isSame(U left, U right) {
        List<Difference> differences = super.isSame( left, right);
        if (!left.getObjectValue3().equals(right.getObjectValue3())) {
            differences.add(new Difference(left.getId(), left.getObjectValue3(), right.getObjectValue3()));
        }
        return differences;
    }
}
```

Test runner:

```
public class RunnerTest {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( "My logger");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BaseObjectData> objectDataList1 = buildList( "id-1", "data-1", "data-2", "data-3b", "data-4");
        List<BaseObjectData> objectDataList2 = buildList( "id-1", "data-1", "data-2a", "data-3", "data-4c");
        List<Difference> differences = new ArrayList<>();
        for( BaseObjectData o: objectDataList1) {
          BaseObjectData o2 = o.findMatchingObject( objectDataList2);
          differences.addAll(o.isSame(o2));
        }
        differences.forEach( v -> logger.info( "Verschil: " + v));
    }

    private static List<BaseObjectData> buildList( String id, String data1, String data2, String data3, String data4) {
        return List.of(
                new BaseObjectData( "B0_"+ id, data1, data2),
                new InheritLevel1Data( "I1_"+ id, data1, data2, data3),
                new InheritLevel2Data( "I2_"+ id, data1, data2, data3, data4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```java
> public class BaseObjectData<T> implements ComparatorBase<T> {
> ```

Allright, for every **caller** that calls `new BaseObjectData`, *it* picks a type. This code has no idea what choice is made and needs to be written such that the code works and makes sense regardless of the choice made. After all, there can be millions of callers and they all can pick different things. The constraint provided is `<T extends Object>` (`<T>` is short for that) - in other words, pretty much no constraint. T can be absolutely anything. The code has to 'work' for all possible choices.

> ```java
> public List<Difference> isSame(T otherObject) {
>        List<Difference> differences = new ArrayList<>();
>        if( !getObjectValue1().equals( > otherObject.getObjectValue1())) {
> ```

Nope. You can't call `getObjectValue1()` on `otherObject`, because `otherObject` is of type `T`, and `T` can be any reference type here. The only methods that **all** reference types have in common is that which `java.lang.Object` defines, so, say, `.hashCode()` is something you are allowed to call here. `getObjectValue1()` is not, and the fact that this mystifies you strongly suggests you completely misunderstand generics and are best off taking a moment to clear your mind and starting from the very beginning.

From there you make even more egregious mistakes such as casting to a generics type - something you should never do, Having raw types in generics (`List<BaseObjectData>` is just not right, it should be `list<BaseObjectData<SomethingGoesHere>>`), and more. But those are also more complex things to explain. In contrast to the trivial mistake of assuming all T have that method.

> Most Java tutorials on "Generics" explain either working with Classes and Methods. That's quite simple.

There's one mistake you've made. They aren't simple. If you think they are you may want to either find another tutorial or pay more attention.

Generics capture a higher level of type information. They attempt to capture new dimensions which involves a completely different ruleset about variance (java types themselves are covariant; an `Integer` is good enough whenever a `Number` is needed because `class Integer extends Number`; in contrast, generics are invariant: `List<Integer>` is no good when a `List<Number>` is needed. But, they have optional variances if you need it: a `List<Integer>` is fine when a `List<? extends Number>` is needed. This on its own is already quite complicated but is inherent to the concept of higher order types. You can't 'just' design a language without this complexity; not without ditching the notion of capturing higher order types in the typing system).

Generics are fully a figment of the compiler's imagination: At runtime little remains and what remains is like a comment to the JVM execution. That's another thing to have to twist your mind around. They serve to link things:

```
public static <T> T printAndReturn(T in) {
  System.out.println(in);
  return in;
}
```

says: The caller gets to pick a type, any type, and this code has no idea what it picked. Every call gets to make their own choice. The one and only thing happening here is that the Ts are linked: Whatever type the caller chose for the parameter, that's *also* what this method returns. Thus, this:

```
String x = printAndReturn("hello");
```

would be valid (T is bound to String, so all Ts are that - the **caller** made this choice, the author of the `printAndReturn` method merely decrees that callers pick a type, it doesn't know what was picked), whereas if you wrote it like:

```
public Object printAndReturn(Object in) {
  System.out.println(in);
  return in;
}
```

Then `String x = printAndReturn("hello");` would **not** compile - because while your eyeballs can clearly see that would 'work', the signature of the method does not actually say that the value returned is identical to `in` and therefore the same type as `in`. Javac does not take the method body into account for such things, thus, you'd have to write `String x = (String) printAndReturn("hello");`. This is mostly what generics are about: Capture such second order concepts as 'the type of the returned value is the same as the type as the parameter, but the caller gets to pick what type that is' in the typing system.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I upvoted your answer. We don't use inheritance in our field much. The issue I had to learn especially was that I thought that an inherited method could contain an inherited argument. That is not correct. Woooaaa, I work with Java since 0.92, but in this Java took me by surpirse ;-)